# Unclear if a vector is perpendicular to a plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Non-mathematician here, so maybe it's a no-brainer for all of you...

I have a construct with three N-dimensional vectors. Vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ together define a 2D plane, question is if the third vector $\mathbf{w}$ is perpendicular to that plane. Problem is that the vector dot-product can not be evaluated, the only information I have is the following: when choosing vectors in that plane with the same length as $\mathbf{w}$, then for each dimension $n$ I can find a vector which has a value in that dimension larger than that of $\mathbf{w}$. When trying to visualize this in 3D I have the idea that $\mathbf{w}$ cannot be perpendicular to the plane, but I have no idea if this is correct, if it's also the case for N dimensions and how a proof or at least a logical argument would look like.

Comment: You need the cross product instead of the dot product.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are asking. But maybe you mean this:- Given any two vectors lying in a plane , we can find a third vector $\mathbf{u\times v}$ which is perpendicular to the plane . Also the term dimension has a very specific meaning in Vector spaces and linear algebra. However I think you are more interested in the $2D$ and the $3D$ space.

Comment: @QBrute: with the dot-product I could check perpendicularity of $\mathbf{w}$ via $(a\mathbf{u}+b\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})=0$. But the dot product cannot be evaluated analytically / closed form in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend to derive the properties of a vector without knowing what the vector is. How are you constructing it?

Comment: @Mr.Gandalf Sauron: No, I do not want to find a third vector which is perpendicular to the plane, I already have the third vector $\mathbf{w}$ and I want to know if it is perpendicular to the plane given the characteristics of the components in each dimension like I described (choose vectors on the plane, make them the same length as $\mathbf{w}$, and then I see that for every dimension $n$ I can find a vector on the plane with a value in that dimension larger than that of $\mathbf{w}$).

Besides that: the crossproduct seems to be ill-defined I think in more than 3 dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with “for each dimension $n$” and “value in that dimension”. Could you try to clarify?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: I was looking at a series (summation over N terms), which I tried to interpret as the dot-product of 2 vectors where 1 vector is 'variable' and describes the plane by $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. Instead of actually calculating the summation itself I was looking for other ways to find characteristics of the summation by looking at characteristics of the vectors. Too long story...

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: what I mean is that if you have N dimensions you can count the dimension with $1\leq n \leq N$. So if I look at the value of $\mathbf{w}$ in dimension $n$, then there is a point on the plane (disc with radius  $|\mathbf{w}|$) which has a higher value for that dimension than $\mathbf{w}$.

It's like $\mathbf{w}$ has an x-coordinate of 0.4, but there is a point on the disc with a larger x-coordinate of 0.5 for example and we have that situation for all other dmensions as well.

Comment: One could consider that you have a kind of "hyper-cylinder C" constructed "above the circle" on which you work in the $(u,v)$ plane, and that you are able to gain information about intersections of C with (other) coordinate axes. And you would like to know if this information is enough to conclude to orthogonality (or not). Is that right ?

Comment: @Jean Marie: Looks like this is a sort of test that could work. The hyper-cylinder $C$ (with radius $|\mathbf{w}|$, how does that look like in N dimensions?) would intersect the infinite length extension of $\mathbf{w}$ when $\mathbf{w}$ is not perpendicular to the disc described by $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ (if I understand correctly...). But given the information I have, how would that work?

Comment: @JeroenBoschma So you have a plane with some vector that defines a cylinder and some vector outside the cylinder and you're trying to show that it's not orthogonal to the plane with the circle in it? If the vector is orthogonal it will always be on the interior of that circle when projected onto the plane so if it's goes outside the cylinder it can't be orthogonal to the plane.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: if you project $\mathbf{w}$ on the plane then, I guess, you get a zero-vector if $\mathbf{w}$ is perpendicular to the plane. But to check this you need to calculate dot products, and the idea was to see if you can do without them and rely only on the information I described earlier.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma you don't have to calculate them if you know they're outside they hypercylinder. This is because they must pierce the cylinder at some point and that point will not be orthogonal to the plane. So in your example the $0.5$ coordinate shows you that it lays outside the $0.4$ cylinder therefore cannot be orthogonal to the plane.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: I don't see that so clearly because the cylinder is not aligned with an axis of the coordinate system. For example I have N=4 with $\mathbf{w}=(1,1,1,1)$ so $|\mathbf{w}|=2$. Then I look at the plane with radius 2, and I can find different points on it, for example (2,0,0,0), (0,2,0,0), (0,0,2,0), (0,0,0,2) [OK, this cannot be a 2D plane but just for numerical example...] so all of length 2 and a value in a certain dimension larger than that of $\mathbf{w}$. From that information, can I conclude that $\mathbf{w}$ is perpendicular to that plane? I still do not see how.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma No you can only conclude that it's *not* perpendicular. It will never actually be orthogonal because, as I said before, if the projection pierces the circle it pierces the cylinder. The coordinates you choose are irrelevant, there merely has to exist some coordinate system where this is true for it to be true in all of them. Orthogonality is fundamentally a geometric property, not a computational one and we don't have to appeal to coordinates to see this is true.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: thanks for your repeated efforts on this, but I am afraid I do not get your point. Maybe a reformulation makes things more clear: I have a vector in $N$ dimensions $\mathbf{w}=(w_1,w_2, ..., w_N)$. I also have a circular plane $P$ which intersects the origin and has radius $|\mathbf{w}|$. For each dimension $1\leq n \leq N$ I can find at least one point on $P$, i.e. $\mathbf{p}=(p_1,p_2, ..., p_N)$ where $p_n > w_n$. Can I conclude from that information that $\mathbf{w}$ is not perpendicular to $P$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sorry but the second part of your sentence "Orthogonality is fundamentally a geometric property, not a computational one and we don't have to appeal to coordinates to see this is true" is false: If I can compute a dot product and find it equal to $0$, I can conclude that the corresponding vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: @JeanMarie you can if you're given a vector but you don't require coordinates or even a vector space to define orthogonality in Euclidean spaces. We did it for centuries with just a compass and straight edge.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma No, it still requires that $p$ be outside the cylinder which means you have to choose a basis where $u,v$ are in the plane and $w$ is orthogonal to it to reach that conclusion using a simple inequality on the coordinates. Otherwise you can fine-tune a counter-example by changing the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the error in my 'conjecture'. It seems to work in 3D, but not in higher dimensions.

A rough sketch for a counter-example:

If you have a vector $\mathbf{w}=(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_{N-1},w_N)$ and assume all $w_n$ are positive for simplicity, you can make a vector $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_{N-1},u_N)$ where you take $u_n=w_n+\delta$ ($\delta$ very small) for all $n<N-1$ and use $u_{N-1}$ and $u_N$ to tune for $|\mathbf{u}|=|\mathbf{w}|$ and $\mathbf{u}$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{w}$. Then follow an equivalent recipe for vector $\mathbf{v}$, where you at least choose $v_{N-1}=w_{N-1}+\delta$ and $v_N=w_N+\delta$, and have the other vector components tuned to $|\mathbf{v}|=|\mathbf{w}|$ and $\mathbf{v}$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{w}$.

So in general, already in 4D, you have enough freedom to construct vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ which form a plane/disc, have characteristics described in my original question with respect to $\mathbf{w}$, but nevertheless $\mathbf{w}$ is perpendicular to the plane/disc.